# Weblogic custom deployer (if really needed)

Tags: java, weblogic11g

We need to implement possibility to update/re-read a file (stored on disk) without redeploying application. The important point is that we have multiple instances of the application working in **Weblogic's** cluster. So my question is: how should **applications** working in cluster **be notified** the FILE has **changed** - does Weblogic has such feature out-of-the-box, or do we need to implement custom deployer for that?

Comment: Is it a configuration file? Is it inside a WAR/EAR/JAR? Is it shared among cluster nodes?

Comment: JBoss AS has such feature. You can dig into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you looking for a hot deployment kind of process(updating the application with modified files), check if my this blog [**Hot Deployment in Weblogic**](http://yogendrakrsingh.blogspot.ca/2010/03/steps-to-configure-hot-deployment-from.html) is helpful to you.

In summary:

1. Add blank `REDEPLOY` file in `MyApplicationEar/APP-INF/META-INF` folder and deploy your application in exploded form.
2. Once any file is updated, update the timestamp of `REDEPLOY` file. This you can achieve simply by recreating the file.
3. Weblogic will scan the file system of the deployed application and redeploy the updated files.

Comment: Thank You, Yogendra. That does makes sense in dev environment